# Is this a Selection sort or Insertion sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Suppose we are sorting an array of ten integers using a some quadratic sorting algorithm. After four iterations of the algorithm's main loop, the array elements are ordered as shown here:

`1 2 3 4 5 0 6 7 8 9`

Which statement is **correct**? (Note: Our selection sort picks largest items first.)
**A**. The algorithm might be either selection sort or insertion sort.
**B**. The algorithm might be selectionsort, but could not be insertionsort.
**C**. The algorithm might be insertionsort, but could not be selectionsort.
**D**. The algorithm is neither selectionsort nor insertionsort.

I think the answer should be A(both Insertion sort and Selection Sort)? But I found on some websites that correct answer is C. I don't know the reason. Could someone please explain me. 
Correct me if I am wrong.

Source : [Google Book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=SoZEBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA285&lpg=PA285&dq=Suppose+we+are+sorting+an+array+of+ten+integers+using+a+some+quadratic+sorting+algorithm.+After+four+iterations+of+the+algorithm%27s+main+loop,+the+array+elements+are+ordered+as+shown+here:&source=bl&ots=_5GIiewdIc&sig=25bHRYMrHHvmdlUm0WSOBiCB0RU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ap1NVeSpBJLhuQTG1oHgBw&ved=0CEsQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=Suppose%20we%20are%20sorting%20an%20array%20of%20ten%20integers%20using%20a%20some%20quadratic%20sorting%20algorithm.%20After%20four%20iterations%20of%20the%20algorithm's%20main%20loop%2C%20the%20array%20elements%20are%20ordered%20as%20shown%20here%3A&f=false)

Comment: When you say online sources state the answer is C, maybe those sources don't include the line "Our selection sort picks largest items first". Without that line, the answer is  C; with it, the answer is A.

Comment: I found the same question with "Note". All sources giving same answer "C".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This output is possible for a largest-first selection sort.

It cannot be a smallest-first selection sort because selection sort keeps the invariant that, after n iterations, the first n items in the list are fully-sorted. So, if this was a selection sort, you would expect that the element with the value 0 would have been sorted to index 0 in the first iteration. Thus, the list would look like `0 1 2 3 ...` after the first 4 iterations.

The output is possible for both a largest-first and smallest-first insertion sort because insertion sort has a different invariant. In an insertion sort, after n iterations, the first n items in the list (last n for a largest-first sort) are sorted with respect to each other, but they're not necessarily in their final position in the list.

For a smallest-first insertion sort, after 4 iterations, it's possible to see the "out of place" 0 because the sort hasn't yet iterated  enough to re-position the 0 in its correct index.

Comment: Since this selection sort starts with the largest items, the fully-sorted segment would actually grow from the back of the list.

Comment: You are correct. I missed that detail in reading the question.

Comment: Then what is the meaning of line (Our selection sort picks largest items first.) ?

Comment: I take it to mean that the selection sort conjectured in the question sorts starting with the largest items in the list, and goes from highest to lowest index. That is, it sorts the array "backwards" starting with 9.

Answer (score 0):

Insertion sort is possible since the current snapshot just finished sorting the array from index 0 up to 4.

Selection sort will pick the minimum value (0 in your example) first and put it to the left end. So the answer is *C*.

Comment: Since this selection sort starts with the largest items, it would actually start by picking 9 and putting it at the right end.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the output of either a largest-first selection sort or an insertion sort. If the array originally looked like that, after 4 iterations of either algorithm, it would still look like that. It couldn't be a smallest-first selection sort, since after 4 iterations of that, the first 4 items of the array would be `0 1 2 3`.

Answer (score 0):

According to me answer is **C.**
*

```
Selection sort-
    for(int x=0; x<n; x++){
        int index_of_min = x;
        for(int y=x; y<n; y++){
            if(array[index_of_min]>array[y]){
                index_of_min = y;
            }
        }
        int temp = array[x];
        array[x] = array[index_of_min];
        array[index_of_min] = temp;
    }
```

*

It is so because in Selection sort you traverse  array right of the x in array and find minimum element in every pass and replace that index with a[x].
In above case

```
1 2 3 4 5 0 6 7 8 9
```

min element is 0 and it should be the leftmost element if selection sort is used because selection sort in the first pass minimum in the whole array should be at a[0]. 
Insertion Sort is possible because in insertion sort we pick up element and keep on comparing the current element with the elements to its left till the current element is at its correct sorted location.What i am trying to say is:
*

```
> Here is an example: for sorting the array the array 52314  First, 2 is
> inserted before 5, resulting in 25314 Then,  3 is inserted between 2
> and 5, resulting in 23514 Next, one is inserted at the start, 12354
> Finally, 4 is inserted between 3 and 5, 12345.
```

*
So Insertion Sort is possible as it has finished sorting up to its fourth pass.